# Python 3.6 type checking: numpy arrays and use defined classes

Tags: python, python-3.6, typechecking

I'd think this has already been asked, but I can't find it

How can one check for non-builtin types in Python 3.6?

For example, let's say I want to have a function foo() that takes a numpy array as an arg, and returns an instance of my class Bah

```
def foo(a: np.array) -> Bah
```

Can I do something like this?  How do I add those types to checking?

Comment: np.ndarray is the type. np.array is just a function

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your code besides that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify anything you want, as a type annotation if the type’s name is in scope (e.g., you’ve defined `Bob` in the current file, or done a `from stuff import`Bob`).

In general, the type checker doesn’t need any special knowledge of the type to know whether a value is that type. If it sees you store the result of this function in a variable whose type is `Bob`, or a supertype of `Bob` (which includes `object` and `Any`, and also includes unannotated variables), that’s legal; if it sees you store it in a variable whose type is `int` or some other unrelated type, it’s not. Similarly, if you pass the result on to some other function whose parameter is `Bob` or `Any` or unannotated, or you append it to a `List[Bob]`, etc.

But `np.array` is a different problem. That isn’t actually a type, it’s just a constructor function that usually returns a value of type `np.ndarray`, which is a type you don’t normally think about anywhere. So, a type checker can’t handle that without some kind of special information that `array` should be treated as a synonym for `ndarray`.

Plus, many NumPy functions—and, implicitly, functions that you write yourself—actually take an “array-like”, which can be an `ndarray`, or usually a `matrix`, but also often any sequence. In which case you probably really want to either annotate then with something closer to accurate, like `typing.Sequence`—or maybe with a custom `ArrayLike` type.

While we’re at it, you often want to specify the dtype—your function doesn’t want an array, it wants an array of floats, or it wants an array of `<something>` and wants to return a `Bob` whose values are that same `<something>`. So, you probably want a generic type like `Sequence[float]` or `Sequence[T]` to some typevar `T`.

And you may even want to require a certain number of dimensions, or even a shape for those dimensions, or even a *partial* shape, or even that parameters `x` and `y` have to be broadcastable together or multiplyable. You can push this information into a generic type, but you’ll have to think it through pretty carefully.

Anyway, for your own types, you rarely have to think that deep. Either `Bob` is a simple type that only needs the standard inheritance rules, so you don’t have to do anything, or it’s a generic collection type, where you just need to inherit/register it as a `MutableSequence` or a `Mapping` or whatever and it automatically gets the appropriate generic rules, or it’s a specific collection type, where you just inherit/register as a `Set[int]` and it automatically gets the approprIate rules.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **typing**. It is a Python library https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

```
import numpy as np
from bar import Bah
from typing import Type

def foo(a: np.ndarray): -> Type[Bah]
    return a.T  #example
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just look at the output of type(a) if you know that a is a numpy array. This will tell you that the class is called "numpy.ndarray". Then check for that by using isinstance(). Like this:

```
import numpy #if you import numpy as np, you need to check for np.ndarray instead

def foo(a):
    if isinstance(a,numpy.ndarray):
        return Blah()
    else:
        print('a needs to be of type numpy.ndarray')
        return
```